# mysql - merge cols into one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to merge few columns into one row in mysql, separated by some char (; or dot), from:

```
Id              Item       Options

1               Charger       iphone
2               Car           black
3               Food          vege
```

into:

```
Items

"Charger; Car; Food"
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in `sql` query or `mysql`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `group_concat()`, presumably:

```
select id, group_concat(item separator '; ') as items
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: thanks, how can I use LIMIT in this query to show only items for example 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, ...?

Comment: @MateuszJi . . . You can add a `WHERE` clause so you filter out items you do not want.